# Activity Picker for Web View in Swift

Tags: ios, animation, swift, uiwebview, uiactivityindicatorview

I am trying to get an Activity Picker to load when the Web View is loading, but for it to disappear when the Web View has loaded.

I tried doing this:

```
class FirstAid: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var FirstAid: UIWebView!
@IBOutlet var activity: UIActivityIndicatorView!


func loadFirstAid(){
    let requestFirstAidURL = NSURL (string: "http://www.nhs.uk/Conditions/Accidents-and-first-aid/Pages/Introduction.aspx")
    let requestFirstAid = NSURLRequest(URL: requestFirstAidURL!)
    FirstAid.loadRequest(requestFirstAid)
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    loadFirstAid()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


func startAnimating(_ : UIWebView!){
    activity.startAnimating()
    activity.hidesWhenStopped = true

}

func stopAnimating(_ : UIWebView!){
    activity.stopAnimating()
    activity.hidesWhenStopped = true

}
```

I have turned on the indicators `Animating` and `Hide while stop` check box and so when the screen loads the indicator, it does spin, but does not go away when the screen has loaded. I have also connected the Web View to the First Aid `delegate` screen.

Can someone tell me where I went wrong and how I can correct it?

Comment: Can you help me with this? @LeonardoSavioDabus

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this code:

```
@IBOutlet var FirstAid: UIWebView!
@IBOutlet var activity: UIActivityIndicatorView!


func loadFirstAid(){
    let requestFirstAidURL = NSURL (string: "http://www.nhs.uk/Conditions/Accidents-and-first-aid/Pages/Introduction.aspx")
    let requestFirstAid = NSURLRequest(URL: requestFirstAidURL!)
    FirstAid.loadRequest(requestFirstAid)
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    FirstAid.delegate = self
    loadFirstAid()
}



func webViewDidStartLoad(webView: UIWebView){

    activity.hidden = false
    activity.startAnimating()

}
func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView){

    activity.hidden = true
    activity.stopAnimating()
    }
}
```

Hope this will help you.